# Error 1009 Class and Function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, class

My code returns Error 1009 for the pickObject function when I click apple object on scene and I really don't understand why? I'm stuck here. Would appreciate some help.

Here is my code on timeline:

```
//INVENTORY
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import inventory.inventorySystem;
import inventory.itemC;
import flash.text.TextField;

var IS:inventorySystem;
var IT:itemC;

apple.itemName = "Apple";
apple.itemIcon = new AppleIcon();

apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);
apple.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUpItem);

pear.itemName = "Pear";
pear.itemIcon = new PearIcon();
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, showItemNameF);
pear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideItemNameF);

function pickUpItem(e:MouseEvent):void{
    IS.addObject(itemC(e.currentTarget));
    removeChild(itemC(e.currentTarget));
}

function showItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var itemNameBox:String;
    itemNameBox = itemC(e.currentTarget).itemName;
    stage.addChild(infoBoxObject);
    infoBoxObject.infoBox.text = itemNameBox;
    infoBoxObject.x = mouseX+12;
    infoBoxObject.y = mouseY;
}

function hideItemNameF(e:MouseEvent):void{
    infoBoxObject.x = -145;
    infoBoxObject.y = 61;
}

//CURSOR

Mouse.hide();
var cursor:cursorImage = new cursorImage();
stage.addChild(cursor);
cursor.startDrag(true);
```

Here is my inventorySystem class:

```
package inventory{

    public class inventorySystem{

        private var slot:Array = new Array(10); 
        public function addObject(it:itemC){
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
                if(slot[i]==null){
                    slot[i] = it;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        public function getObject(i:int):itemC{
            return slot[i];
        }

        public function useObject(i:int){
            slot[i] = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my itemC class:

```
package inventory{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class itemC extends MovieClip{

        public var itemName:String;
        public var itemIcon:MovieClip;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks to Petr, code works perfectly now and my icons appear in my inventory. My new problem is, I want to show the name of the object when I mouse_move on item icon too, as I did it with the objects themselves (showItemNameF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `IS` is declared, but not initialized. Try to change:

```
var IS:inventorySystem;
```

to:

```
var IS:inventorySystem = new inventorySystem();
```